# iOS 12 safari auto scrolls to autofill password

Tags: safari, autoscroll, ios12

I've just installed iOS 12 on my iPhone and when I am browsing in safari, page autoscroll to input field at the bottom of the page.

It turns out that `Settings -> Safari -> Autofill -> Use contact` info is messing up the page. When autofill turned off, the page is loading just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that element id was `id="comment-username"` and safari was auto-open password prompt.

Just changed id name and that did the trick.